# how to add a document to an array in mongodb using powershell code?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, powershell

I would like to insert a document into an array within another document in **Powershell**.

e.g.

```
{
        "1" : "A",
        "2" : "B",
        "3" : [
                {
                        "a" : "AA",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5333b74c9e99569836bca41f")
                }
        ],
        "_id" : ObjectId("5333b74c9e99569836bca41c")
}
```

this is my document in mongodb shell.

```
{
        "1" : "A",
        "2" : "B",
        "3" : [ ]
        "_id" : ObjectId("5333b74c9e99569836bca41c")
}
```

and this is my code in powershell:

```
$embededDocument = new-object Mongodb.Bson.BsonDocument
$embededDocument.Add("a", "AA")
$embededDocument.Add("B2", "2")
$embededDocument.Add("C2", "3")

$parentDocument["3"].Add($embededDocument)
```

this is not working as the array is empty after run the code, I tried using Add, Insert and Push with same result...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are trying to do an update of the type that is shown for the [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator, as shown in the documentation. So you need to construct the same sort of BSON document structure as shown there:

```csharp
$query = [MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query]::EQ("_id" :
    [MongoDB.Bson.BsonObjectId]::Create("5333b74c9e99569836bca41c"))

$doc = new-object MongoDB.Bson.Document
$doc.Add("a", "AA")

$inner = new-object MongoDB.Bson.Document
$inner.Add( "3", $doc )

$update = new-object MongoDB.Bson.Document
$update.Add('$push', $inner)

$collection.update($query,$update)
```

This comes out the be the equivalent of this:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("5333b74c9e99569836bca41c") },
    {
        "$push": { "3": { "a": "AA" } }
    }
)
```

MongoDB does not create `ObjectId` values automatically inside array elements in the way you have shown. If you want to create them then you need to add the fields and created `ObjectId` values yourself.

For any other reference, use the [C# documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/) which is essentially the API you are using with powershell.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the push operation or such like that,you are supposed to call the `save()` after that or I don't think your document would be saved.
As a result, your array will always be null.